# Azure Active Directory Oauth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow with API Management Access Token issue

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I have had been struggling to make my Azure Active Directory Oauth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow work with API Management. but I get authenticated via postman too. But in return I do not get any access token just a bunch of HTML. How can I fix this? The settings of the applications are exactly as per the documents including the validation of JWT Policy.

Basically I want my client apps to connect with my azure API's using Oauth 2.o without any consent using provided client id/secret. I'm trying to set this up for now with ECHO API provided out of the box with API Management console.

thanks

[Postman Access token Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1wQJ.png)

Comment: I figured that the problem is the with the scope. As soon as I replace the my app's scope with https://graph.microsoft.com/.default . Everything seems to be working fine. Why

Comment: Can't I use the scopes I'm defining to get authenticated. with my Custom Scope I get errors

Comment: Error: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named api://<id>/app_permissions_allow was not found in the tenant named <ad-id>. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong. This only happens when I use my scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use application permissions with your own API (as opposed to Microsoft Graph), you must first [expose the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis) by defining scopes in the API's app registration in the Azure portal. Then, [configure access to the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis) by selecting those permissions in your client application's app registration. If you haven't exposed any scopes in your API's app registration, you won't be able to specify application permissions to that API in your client application's app registration in the Azure portal.

[image]

For an example, if I sent scope parameter with custom name like https://testwebapp.in/.default without configuring same as application ID URI in Azure AD then is an expected behavior and you will get error AADSTS500011.

`scope` parameter in the request should be the resource identifier (application ID URI) of the resource you want, affixed with the .default suffix. For the Microsoft Graph example, the value is https://graph.microsoft.com/.default. This value tells the Microsoft identity platform that of all the direct application permissions you have configured for your app, the endpoint should issue a token for the ones associated with the resource you want to use.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#application-permissions